# How to get list of file names inside a specific folder in stash repository using stash rest API in Java

Tags: java, git, bitbucket-server

I have a project in stash repository(master).That master can have many branches.I have a folder hierarchy in master like `src/test`.Inside that folder contains files.`(test.xml,test2.xml)`.Is there any way to get list of raw file names using [Stash REST](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.5.1/stash-rest.html) api.Also i would like to know that how can i get list of files from specific branch like above mentioned.

**Get list of available branches**

```
http://example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/branches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to do it.REST call look like this.

**Branch name**

```
feature/test 

 https://stash.project.local/rest/api/1.0/projects/DEV/repos/test/browse/src/plan?at=feature/test
```

Comment: I don't think the above will give you the list of "raw" file names.

Comment: 4 years later, this was exactly what I needed. Thanks Stack Overflow. :)